# Security risk of purchasing Android phone with unlocked boot loader but using/flashing known good firmware?

Tags: bootloader-lock

(If its easier for the question, we can assume a non-ancient version of Android - say Android 12 or newer)

I am aware that running an unlocked boot loader can allow hacked firmware to be run on the phone, but understand that Android - or at least some versions of android/some distributions - offer at least some warning/protections (i.e. a warning if the firmware is unsigned).

For various reasons (warranty related) I would like to purchase a phone with a boot loader that is unlocked.   **Assuming that either I flash known good firmware or that the installed firmware is signed** is there any risk of the phone being compromised over and above the risks if I unlocked the boot loader myself?

Comment: If the bootloader is unlocked it doesn't matter if the firmware is signed, this is one of the features you disable by unlocking a bootloader. So in the end it is a question of trust - who is offering a phone with warranty and unlocked bootloader?

Comment: @robert that is not correct - at least not on a Samsung A24.  If the bootloader is unlocked it does not throw any warnings, but if the firmware is unsigned it does.